# Building Combinations of Items with Specific joining rules

Tags: .net, algorithm, conditional-statements, combinations

I am attempting to generate all possible combinations of a set of objects with specific properties. The issue is that these objects can only be combined in certain ways and that when you "validate" the object combination as a whole it must meet certain conditions.

The object data is stored in a SQL Server database (that I have complete control over, so it can change if the data needs to be arranged differently)

A simplified version of the objects I'm dealing with is

```
class Item { 
public string Start {get;set;}
public string End {get;set;}
}
```

If I have a list of these objects for example:

1. Item {Start = "A", End = "B"}
2. Item {Start = "B", End = "C"}
3. Item {Start = "B", End = "A"}

The resulting output of this set of items would be:

A -> B
 B -> C
 B -> A
 A -> B -> C

e.g.
Item 1 can be combined with Item 2 to produce A -> B -> C.
But Item 2 cannot be combined with Item 3 because the End value of Item 2 does not match the Start value of Item 3.

Also there are "overall" rules where the overall combination of Start and Ends cannot result in the items going:
A -> B -> A
(item 1 with item 3).

There can be up to 5 of these items joined together.

Is there any generic way of doing this or algorithm that achieves the same result?

Any help (even pointers) would be appreciated.

Comment: Google for "Directed Graphs" and cycles, There is a whole world in your hands

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with a query in the database, you can look into [Recursive Queries Using Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx).